# Is there a default color table / colormap available in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt5

I can't seem to find a default or any provided colormap in `Qt` (5.7 in my case).

All I find is people generating their own color table such as:

```
QVector<QRgb> ctable;
for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    ctable.append(qRgb(i,i,i));
}
```

So is there any colormap available in `Qt` (as there is in matplotlib or matlab like here ?

[image]

Edit: a colormap to go with `QImage::Format_Indexed8` image format and `QImage::setColorTable()`

**A solution, as Qt does not provide any colormap:**

I downloaded a colormap from AMA's link http://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-advice/black-body/black-body-table-byte-0256.csv

Then I read the file to generate my own colormap:

```
QVector<QRgb> ctable;

QFile file("black-body-table-byte-0128.csv");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QMessageBox::information(0, "error", file.errorString());
}

QTextStream in(&file);

while(!in.atEnd())
{
    QString line = in.readLine();    
    QStringList values = line.split(",");
    ctable.append(qRgb(values[1].toInt(), values[2].toInt(), values[3].toInt()));
}

file.close();
```

now `ctable` can be used as a colormap using:

```
QImage myImage;
myImage.setColorTable(ctable);
```

Comment: Qt has predefined colors: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#GlobalColor-enum. You can use it as input of a new QColor instance: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#QColor-1

Comment: @Antwane I am looking for a colormap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, unfortunately Qt does not provide any. You will have to build it yourself. 
But there are plenty of sources with color table values for all sorts of needs.

---

**Edit:** I successfully used some perceptually uniform colormaps from http://www.kennethmoreland.com for my data visualization needs.

Comment: thank you for this link, I edited my question to provide a colormap using this website.